# Using Windows 10, how to "sync" documents, pictures, videos... folders with USB drive backup?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, backup, sync

I have a backup of the documents, pictures and videos folders on a large external USB drive which took many hours to create. - Hey, even cloud services can lose files, as I found out to my cost

I now have new files and modified copies of others which I need to copy to the backup USB drive.

Is there a quicker way to update ("sync") the backup with the new and modified files in Windows 10 without `select all` > `copy to USB` then waiting hours for the PC to ask if I want to overwrite the modified duplicates once it has gone through the files?

Comment: What O.S. are you using? My favorite tools are the ones mentioned by @Madhubala in their answer: *rsync* for Linux and *Robocopy* for Windows. Both involve some scripting. For Windows there was once a tool by Microsoft called *SyncToy* that worked very well but does not seem to be supported by Microsoft anymore.

Comment: Oops @StarCat sorry, it's Windows 10. I'll edit that into the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try using

1. ***rsync***

`--ignore-existing`

skip updating files that exist on receiver

```
-b, --backup
```

With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as
each file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the
backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using
the --backup-dir and --suffix options

2. ***robocopy***

> /xo:

Excludes older files - if destination file exists and is the same date or newer than the source - don't bother to overwrite it.

3. ***For gui use [freefilesync](https://freefilesync.org/)***

Comment: You mentioned using `/xo` (exclude older files) but would I need `/im` (include modified files)? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: @ChrisRogers you can, but the problem with "modified" is that you may have modified the file on both sides, thus creating two separate branches of the files. If you're not concerned about data loss then including modified files is the way to go.